# Android : How to make enable the button of one Activity in other Activity - without using static?

Tags: android

I have a login Activity where I can give username and password. If both are true then just am disabling the button and calling other Activity (MainActivity).

If I press back from MainActivity then I want to make enable submit button in the LoginActivity and am setting the username and password as empty.

This is my code.

```
private Boolean exit = false;
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (exit)
        {

        }
        else {

            MainActivity.this.finish();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Press Back again to Exit.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            exit = true;
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    exit = false;
                    LoginActivity.user_name.setText("");
                    LoginActivity.password.setText("");
                    LoginActivity.loginsubmit.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }, 100);

        }

    }
```

Here am using static. But I want to do this without using static. Could someone give me an idea?

Comment: use some intent with extra, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to static just override onResume() in LoginActivity like :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    user_name.setText("");
    password.setText("");
    loginsubmit.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: I have tried a similar solution but having no luck.  I would appreciate if you could take a look and offer any advice:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40372223/android-how-do-i-setenabledtrue-on-a-cardview-in-onresume

Answer (score 1):

Add below code to onBackPressed() of MainActivity,

```
Intent loginIntent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
loginIntent.putExtra("username", "");
loginIntent.putExtra("password", "");
loginIntent.putExtra("isSubmitEnabled", true);
loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(loginIntent);
```

And add below code to onCreate() of LoginActivity,

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

if (intent != null) {
        String username = intent.getStringExtra("username");
        String password = intent.getStringExtra("password");
        boolean isSubmitEnabled = intent.getBooleanExtra("isSubmitEnabled",
                false);
    }
```

Using above username, password, and isSubmitEnabled flag you can achieve the required.

You can use below code,

```
user_name.setText(username);
password.setText(password);
loginsubmit.setEnabled(isSubmitEnabled );
```