# Android: how do I setEnabled(true) on a CardView in onResume?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a RecyclerView list with CardViews.  I added the following code below to launch an activity (ActActivity) that allows the user to edit the CardView.  The `setEnabled(false)` code is used to keep multiple instances of the activity from opening if the user clicks multiple times in rapid succession on the CardView.  I only want one instance of the activity to be open at one time so that the user is only editing the single CardView that they clicked on.

My problem is that when I add the `onResume()` section to re-set `setEnabled()` to "true" the app crashes.  When I remove the onResume() section then the setEnabled(false) code works correctly by not allowing multiple instances of the activity to open, but the problem is that any doubleclicks on the CardView disable a future single-click to correctly launch the ActActivity.

What am I missing here?

```
MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    RecyclerItemClickListener {

    lvContact = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.lvContact);
    assert lvContact != null;
    lvContact.setHasFixedSize(true);

    contactListAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(this);
    contactListAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    lvContact.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    lvContact.setAdapter(contactListAdapter);  
...
@Override
public void onItemClick(int position, View view) {
    CardView c = (CardView) view;
    c.setEnabled(false);
    ActActivity.start(this, contactListAdapter.getItem(position));
}

...
Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    CardView cardView1 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.singlecard_view1);
    cardView1.setEnabled(true);
}
```

xml file for the RecyclerView:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
tools:context="com.v050.MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" >
</include>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/todoListLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_above="@+id/s4"
    android:background="@color/background4main"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"  >

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/lvContact"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"  />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/s4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:clickable="true"  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

xml file for the CardView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/singlecard_view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:longClickable="true"  >
```

Logcat output does not like the "cardView1.setEnabled(true)" line in the onResume() section:

```
11-01 23:22:54.814 1399-1399/com.example.v50 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.v50/com.v050.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2575)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2089)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.v050.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:279)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1184)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5082)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2565)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2089) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

One proposed answer that works is:

```
...     
@Override
public void onItemClick(int position, final View view) {
    view.setEnabled(false);
    ActActivity.start(this, contactListAdapter.getItem(position));
    view.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
 }
```

How does this compare to answers that use onResume?

Comment: If the app crashes please post your logcat info

Comment: Can we have your error log?

Comment: Sure, will add that now.

Comment: Added logcat info.

Comment: Looks like the `CardView` is null after the call to `findViewById`. What does the `Activity` layout look like?

Comment: @cascal I will add the Activity layout above.

Comment: @cascal Activity layout added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is problem .....

`CardView` is in the `recycle view` and you are trying from the `main layout` instead of `item layout` ....

> here is your solution for your problem....

create `cardview` variable as `global` .......

```
private CardView cardview;
```

use it when the `item clicked` ......

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(int position, View view) {
    cardview = (CardView) view;
    cardview.setEnabled(false);
    ActActivity.start(this, contactListAdapter.getItem(position));
}
```

**Note:- Always try to declare global variable which have use in many methods ....**.

**EDIT:-** try this for the first run in your `onResume`....

and put condition onResume ....

```
 Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(cardview!=null){
        cardview.setEnabled(true);

     }
```

**above problem will solve your First Run problem ....**

Comment: I will try.  Another suggested this:   public void onItemClick(int position, final View view) {
        view.setEnabled(false);
        ActActivity.start(this, contactListAdapter.getItem(position));
        view.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                view.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    }  This works well.  Do you have an opinion on this solution versus the solution using the onResume code?

Comment: It will crash on the first run as `cardview` will be `null` when `onResume` is called for the first time

Comment: @sushildh App crashes.

Comment: have look on edit Answer... it solve your problem. You don't require any thread for this ......

Comment: @Rehan why will it crash on first run?

Comment: Ok.  App crashes.  Is "if(firstFlag)..." correct?  Should it be "if(!firstFlag)..."

Comment: @sushildlh Remove the first run check and add `null` check because it will still crash if the activity goes to `onResume` second time and `onItemClick` is not called.

Comment: @sushildlh That did the trick.  I appreciate your expertise and time to help me solve this one.  Answer accepted and upvoted.  Cheers.

Comment: @Rehan  I appreciate the refinements you recommended to make it perfect and the explanations to help me understand.  All the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialise the card view in onCreate of activity instead of onResume.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    CardView cardView1 = (CardView)findViewById(R.id.singlecard_view1);
    } 

    Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    cardView1.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

Comment: Ok I will try it.

Comment: Same result.  App crashes and logcat says is caused by line: "cardView1.setEnabled(true);"

Comment: You have to check null condition before accessing cardView. Because onResume will be called initially.

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized the RecyclerView contact list before following code:

> CardView cardView1 = (CardView)findViewById(R.id.singlecard_view1);

If you haven't then the card view will not be created and `findViewById(R.id.singlecard_view1);`
 will return null.

**Edited:**
I think the view of the RecyclerView's items are not getting initialized untill activity is fully visible which cause `findViewById(R.id.singlecard_view1)` return null.

But as you have said you just want the edit activity to be started only once.
You can achieve this by
-> adding    `android:launchMode="singleTask"` for "ActActivity" in manifest file. 
OR
->adding FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK to Intent.

Comment: Yes, the list is created and then the user clicks on one of the CardViews to edit it.  I am trying to keep multiple instances of the same CardView from opening up.

Comment: Where are you initializing the list? I mean setting it's layout-manager and adapter.

Comment: See edit above, it's at the top of the MainActivity file.